Unable to detect MapboxLayer from deck.gl/mapbox
Following this.
I have following in my package.json:
{
  "name": "cesium-deckgl-viewer-vite",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "~5.6.2",
    "vite": "^6.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@deck.gl/core": "^9.0.38",
    "@deck.gl/geo-layers": "^9.0.38",
    "@deck.gl/mapbox": "^9.0.38",
    "@loaders.gl/3d-tiles": "^4.3.3",
    "@loaders.gl/core": "^4.3.3",
    "@probe.gl/log": "^4.0.9",
    "mapbox-gl": "^3.8.0"
  }
}

And in my index.js:
import {MapboxLayer} from '@deck.gl/mapbox';

But it gives me error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/@deck__gl_mapbox.js?v=5cb1e8a3' does not provide an export named 'MapboxLayer'

What is missing in my setup?

Did you run npm install? Seems like there's no folder inside your node_modules.
Also did you follow the installation guide?

yes, I ran 'npm install', and I can see folders in node_modules.

Seems like you are using @deck.gl/mapbox v9.
Check the documentation here, it say: MapboxLayer has been removed. Use MapboxOverlay instead.

Thanks, it helped. A query though. My point cloud shows up suspended in air. Any idea, why so?

Need more context about that... Try to search something on web or in other thread. Feel free to open a new question!
